# why is my browser getting js first?

Tags: javascript

I've put all my js files at the bottom of the html but when I'm looking with firebug (in firefox) the js are called just after the html document.

Any solutions? I can do a load of js with onLoad but I would like to know the issue first.

Thanks,
Claudiu

**Update**:
I have

```
[html]

 [head]

   //stuf with no js files included

 [/head]

 [body]

   //content

   [script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"][/script]

    [script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"][/script]

    [script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"][/script]

 [/body]

[/html]
```

But the javascript is loaded first (as you can see in the picture - firebug - net):

[image]

Comment: Do you by any chance mean you want images to load before JS?

Comment: yes, js should load last

Answer (score 3):

The browser parses from top to bottom. Any scripts right at the end of the HTML document before the end body tag will be executed pretty much at the time of when the DOM is loaded since the browser has parsed everything beforehand.

If you need to bind event handlers to the window's load event, do so in your scripts  to delay them a bit longer through `window.onload` or `window.addEventListener('load')` or more preferably a cross-browser event system.

If you need to execute javascript before the DOM being ready, in advance, move a script to the `<head>` so it gets read first.

It would be great if you can actually clarify since the question is *somewhat* confusing, though with a real-world example of what you need.

**EDIT**: You are placing the scripts after the DOM is loaded. Images are not all loaded at that point, it's only during the window's `load` event.

There's really no reason why you should load those scripts after the images load... I would guestimate that 99.99% of websites using js/jquery have the same load order as you do at the moment..

If you really need this, just use a script injection method on the window's `load` event.